# Do captured familiars' stats vary a lot?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I have 2 Tokotoko's that I have caught over a period of time. Both are in my Familiar Retreat and I havent yet trained them or used them in battle. First curious thing to note is that they are caught at Lv.1, because 2nd stage familiars are usually caught at Lv.10.
Second Curious thing is the difference between their stats:

```
Atk:   27  27
Def:   27  27
M.Atk: 45  45
M.Def: 51  120
Acc:   26  32
Eva:   71  122
```

Note the staggering difference in their Magic Defense and Evasion stat! Is there a reason for this difference?
Do all familiars have such normal & super stat versions when they are caught?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the type of familiars. According to the [Ni No Kuni Wiki](http://ninokuni.wikia.com),you need to look up the "Wizards Companion", under the section of familiar to find out what their favorite treats are, and feed their favorites accordingly. However, the best familiars with the best stats are limited to dozens.

[This GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/998014-ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/65295773) article tells you the familiars with the best stats, and [this IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/Familiars) article explains the locations of EVERY familiar that are in the game:

What I would recommend is to just feed the starting familiars with their favorite foods (such as Mite, Drongo, and Thumbelemur)

If you are looking for a good non-starting familiar, I would recommend that you acquire Bonehead; it can be found in Shimmering Sands Desert[image] and it looks like this:[image](Bonehead A is the one you are looking for in the picture)

You can find more about this familiar on this site: http://ninokuni.wikia.com/wiki/Bonehead

Happy Gaming!

Comment: It's just my side information, but if people wanna know, Billy Goat's Bluff South is a good place to farm for exp for your familiars! Such a place is accessible as soon as you get your "Fly" ability.

Comment: Boneheads hit HARD, physically. I mean SUPER STRONK. (with enough levels and favorite food)

Answer (score -1):

The captured familiars have set changes of stats unless you give them items.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail and information in your answer? As it is, you might get a few downvotes because it's quite basic and doesn't really cover the question in any depth.